# Plot single point on geom_line without a y-value in the data frame?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am looking to add a single point to my ggplot geom_line at a specific x-value. The x-value where I want the point to fall does not have an associated y-value in the data frame; however, I want the point to fall on the line.

```
df <- mtcars
ggplot(df,aes(disp,wt)) +
  geom_line() +
  geom_point() +
  geom_point(aes(x=200),color="red")
```

Ideally, I will only have one red point at x=200 and the point will fall on the ggplot geom_line(). Any information on how to do this is greatly appreciated--thank you!

Comment: I think you'll need to calculate the y value for that point on the line.

Comment: Search for “[r] interpolation” and you should find some relevant advice. Eg https://stackoverflow.com/q/6720890/6851825

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `approx` to find the y-value. And I'd recommend using `annotate()` instead of a `geom_*` function to add one-offs to a graph.

```
ggplot(df, aes(disp,wt)) +
  geom_line() +
  geom_point() +
  annotate(
    geom = "point", 
    x = 200, 
    y = approx(x = df$disp, y = df$wt, xout = 200)$y,
    color="red"
)
```

[image]